# Graceful connection closing using iptables

Tags: iptables

I'm developing a transparent HTTP proxy for fault injection testing. The proxy needs to capture all traffic to a HTTP server in order to selectively inject faults.

The transparent proxy sets an `iptables` rule that redirects all traffic to a given port to the port it is listening. This part works.

However, it must also force all existing clients to reconnect or the transparent proxy will not have effect on existing connections.

I'm doing this using an `iptables` rule that resets established connection with `"-j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset`.

This works well in general, but in some cases the clients are not able to handle the `tcp-reset` and terminate.

I'm looking for a way to do the same but with a graceful termination.

My understanding is that a package with the `FIN` flag should accomplish this, but I haven't found a way to generate such package.

Comment: I don't think that iptables is the right tool for that.